# How to lower down the size of dockerized .Net Core apps?

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

*I normally use Rider for that but for reproduction purposes I will describe the process by using the terminal*

I created a .Net 5 Web Api and want to add Docker support for it. I tried to get into it by playing around with a sample app. So with the terminal I create a new Web Api

```
mkdir project
cd project
dotnet new sln
dotnet new webapi -o Api
dotnet sln add ./Api
```

I check that everything is fine with

```
cd Api
dotnet run
call https://localhost:5001/weatherforecast in the browser
close with ctrl + c
```

Inside the Api project I create a Dockerfile with this content

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=build /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "Rest.dll" ]
```

I also create a .dockerignore file with this content

```
.git
Dockerfile
bin/
obj/
```

I'm building the image with

```
docker build -t api .
```

When I now run

```
docker images
```

this image has a size of 209MB. I would like to know if this is "the best/right way to go" or if there is something I can improve in the Dockerfile or .dockerignore file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There should be a slim variant of the images, so you build in the SDK image and copy the outputs into the prod (slim) image. It will still be of order ~100 MB.

Comment: You may look at `alpine` images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can base your Dockerfile off a smaller image. Searching the catalogue of available images in the [Microsoft container registry (MCR) here](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-sdk), the Linux alpine (*5.0-alpine*) is probably the most lightweight. Note that for the other distros, there may be a regular and slim variant, where the regular is the SDK environment and the slim is the production environment.

Then you can structure your Dockerfile as follows to move the artefacts from the build output in the SDK image to the final lightweight deployment image:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app

# Main build (SDK environment)
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
RUN dotnet restore "webapi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/webapi"
RUN dotnet build "webapi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

# Publish build outputs to /app dir
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "webapi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

# Final deployment image
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "api.dll"]
```

In my example, I've used the Debian buster SDK image for the build stage and the buster slim for deployment.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer. Unfortunately your provided solution confuses me. Do I have to use the 3.1 core runtime instead of .net 5? And what needs to run here `... dotnet restore and build project into /app/build dir` ?

Comment: @Question3r, I have added an example of the build step, I'm not sure about the project/file naming. Hope it helps :)

Comment: I'm not sure about this solution. Same as before, do you think I have to use the 3.1 core image instead of the .net 5 one? and why do you call `RUN dotnet restore "webapi.csproj"` explicitly, shouldn't be `RUN dotnet restore` fine enough?

Comment: @Question3r If you want to use a NET5.0 one, then you can, just replace 3.1 with 5.0.

Comment: @Question3r regarding your second point, it may not any difference but better to be specific when you can be to avoid potential ambiguity. If you had a VS solution file in the same folder, then I'm not sure if the restore would restore all package for the solution, but because I specified what I want, I don't have that problem.

Comment: @Question3r is anything still unclear about the answer?

Comment: I tried to play around with it and the smallest I can get is this one https://hatebin.com/rzwenawfkd with 209 MB. It's more flexible since it has less hardcoded names in it

Comment: For a container that has the dotnet runtimes and dependencies, that's about as small as you get. You can also pick a minimal image and install deps yourself.